# Perl/Regex - Replace character after a comma

Tags: regex, perl

I need help with a string manipulator either using Perl or Regex

I need to replace the "g" character after the "," with an "l"

Before

```
testWord1,go
```

After

```
testWord1,lo
```

What would be the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: This is an extremely simply problem, and the issue seems to be that you don't know any Perl at all. Stack Overflow isn't a good place to learn a language

Answer (score 3):

You can use positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=,)g
```

It matches "g" that is preceded by a ",".

Here's a demonstration:

```
~$ echo testWord1,go | perl -ne 's/(?<=,)g/l/g; print;'
testWord1,lo
```

Answer (score 2):

use in perl script

```
s/,g/,l/g
```

- `s`(first one): for substitute
- `g`(last one): global

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
my $str = "testWord1,go";
$str =~ s/,g/,l/;
print $str, "\n";
```

Output:

```
testWord1,lo
```